# Количество видимых элементов в ActionBar

Tags: android

Как определить, сколько элементов отрисовано на ActionBar? 
Или как определить, сколько находятся в overflow(появляются при клике на кнопку меню)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в документации google

```
The screen width in density-independent pixels (dp) determine the number of items that will fit in the main action bar:
smaller than 360 dp = 2 icons
360-499 dp = 3 icons
500-599 dp = 4 icons
600 dp and larger = 5 icons
```

Answer (score 1):

привет , попробуй как вот здесь предлагают 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689759/is-it-possible-to-get-the-number-of-menu-items-displayed-in-the-action-bar
Сам я не уверен потому что не пробовал, но если попробовать как в 1 ответе то может получится